# Solving the differential equation $y'' - y = \text{sinh}^3(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As written in the title, I am trying to solve the differential equation (for y)

$$y'' - y = \text{sinh}^3(x)$$

I know that if we have $\text{sinh}(x)$ instead, we can propose a particular solution with the linear combination of $\text{sinh}(x)$ and $\text{cosh}(x)$. I am unsure with $\text{sinh}^3(x)$. I am simply looking for a particular solution to the problem (not the homogeneous part). Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\sinh^3(x) = \dfrac{\sinh(3 x)-3 \sinh(x)}{4} $. Also: Have you considered using the definition of $\sinh(x) = \dfrac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$?

Comment: Perhaps it is reasonable to apply Fourier transform to find a specific solution, then you can check if this solution if valid for your equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sinh x={\frac {e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}}$$
$$\sinh^3 x={\frac {e^{3x}-3e^{x}+3e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{8}}$$
so 
the particular solution is
$$y_p=Ae^{3x}+Be^x+Ce^{-x}+De^{-3x}$$

Comment: I disapprove the silent downvote, this is a perfectly appropriate hint.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The derivative of an homogeneous trigonometric polynomial is also  an homogeneous trigonometric polynomial, so you can try

$$y=a\cosh^3x+b\cos^2x\sinh x+c\cosh x\sinh^2x+d\sinh^3x.$$

Substitute in the LHS and identifiy to the RHS.